# Error ORA-04062

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I'm currently working with an application on Oracle Forms & Reports 6i with a 10g database that has packages, this application has Over 900 .fmb/fmx files and Over 700 .rep/rdf files. I have copied the application to another computer, and now it's giving me these errors on most of the forms:

```
FRM-40735: XXXXXX trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-04062.
```

Or

```
ORA-04062 signature of package BLABLA has been changed
```

I figured out that i have to recompile the form for it to work, and it did, but as i said i have many forms and it's time consuming to recompile all the forms and packages every time i change the computer.

Where the problem comes from? and what can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is also an issue with PL/SQL when a remote database session calls a PL/SQL function, procedure or package via database link to the database server, and the code on the server has a newer timestamp than the last time the client called it.

The remote_dependencies_mode parameter defaults to checking the *timestamp* of the stored code.  It can be changed to *signature* to avoid the ORA-4062 error.

This is probably not something you would change at an instance level.

What I have used in PL/SQL:

```
execute immediate q'[alter session set remote_dependencies_mode = 'SIGNATURE']';
```

This may or may not work with Forms.

If all else fails, it could be set in a session via a logon trigger if this is an issue you regularly have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-04062 error occurs when the spec of a database package used by the Form has changed. Moving the Forms from one client to another shouldn't cause this unless the target database has changed too.

Part of the problem is that you're working with a really version of Forms.  But I guess upgrading is not an option (because you need the client/server version).

Do you need to compile all the Forms? How many Forms use the affected package? If you must compile a lot of Forms the easiest thing to do is write a `.bat` script to compile them.